# getimagesize() with SWF stopped working?

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, swfobject

Ages ago I made a portal for flash games. Recently I find that on every single game page the game  window size is completely wrong, all of them are **300x200.** It's surprising because I haven't touched the site since I made it, and back then it was working perfectly.

It's been a while since I used PHP but I track down the problem to either these two:

1. **getimagesize()**
2. **SWFObject**

Here is the php code using **getimagesize()** with the **.swf**

```
$gameUrl = "/games/".$gameName."/".$gameName.".swf";
$gameSize = getimagesize('http://www.pixelbear.com'.$gameUrl);
$gameWidth = $gameSize[0];
$gameHeight= $gameSize[1];
```

And here is the usage of **SWFObject**

```
<div id="gamebox"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject("<?php echo $gameUrl; ?>", "<?php echo $gameName; ?>", "<?php echo $gameWidth; ?>", "<?php echo $gameHeight; ?>", "6", "");
so.write("gamebox");
</script>
```

Everything is running with **PHP 5.4**

**http://www.pixelbear.com/game/goin-up**

Don't really know what to do here.

Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: `http://www.pixelbear.com/games/xxxx/xxxx.swf[0]` What does this mean?

Comment: Since it can't find game called `xxxx` it will simply go back to the main page. Some `.htaccess` trickery going on.